# Quote on chemistry - who is the author?

Tags: quotes

I have seen this quote often:

> Chemistry is like cooking - just don't lick the spoon

Sometimes in the version of a parenthesis around the latter part to give it it's sub-humoristic meaning.

Often I can find quote sites that attribute the author to a quote. But this particular one seems to be unknown on many sites ([example](https://me.me/i/chemistry-is-like-cooking-just-dont-lick-the-spoon-unknown-15074355)). Do anyone know the author of this quote?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because tracing down authors of humorous quotes is not in site scope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oldest published *version* of this I find is in the Feb 1971 edition of Boy's Life magazine in their joke column, [*Think and Grin*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NYYu35CIIgsC&pg=PA78&dq=chemistry%20%27dont%20lick%20the%20spoon%27&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG-s-I-djdAhXIoFMKHWFzCtMQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Student: What;'s the first lesson on Chemistry?
>
> Prof: Don't lick the spoon.

it was submitted by Paul Medrek, East Longmeadow, Mass.